# Error 0x800703F1 while starting Windows 7 Backup utility

Tags: windows-7, windows, backup, restore

This started some time ago. I'm making backup to my Apple Time Capsule drive. How to fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

It's an error code generated while your last backup fails, [refer here to know more about this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/last-backup-did-not-complete-sucsessfully-error/2f9fd67f-d0aa-4d81-89f7-dd8ba9d87975).

Per Microsoft users community, you can retry to run the backup with an administrator account.

Comment: Creating new user did not help...